# Building maciejhirsz/logos on Rust nightly-2020-06-13

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a project using Rust nightly with [logos 0.11.4](https://github.com/maciejhirsz/logos) as a dependency. When I run `cargo build`, I get

```
error: failed to download `logos v0.11.4`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `C:\Users\jonat\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\logos-0.11.4\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  readme file with name '../README.md' was not found
```

It turns out that logos has a nested package called [logos-derive](https://github.com/maciejhirsz/logos/tree/master/logos-derive), and the Cargo.toml for this project has the line `readme = "../README.md"`. In other words, it's pointing to the README from the parent directory. However, the Cargo source registry places the `logos-0-11.4` and `logos-derive-0.11.5` directories at the same level, rather than nesting them, which explains why the file is not found. I can actually get it to build by creating an empty `.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/README.md`. But that's obviously not a satisfactory long-term fix.

Note that I was able to build just fine two days ago (2020-06-11), but despite there not being any changes to logos or logos-derive in that time, I'm now unable to build - even after checking out my project from that time and downgrading my toolchain to `nightly-2020-06-11`. I'm not sure how that's possible or what in my build process has changed.

Am I doing something wrong, is `logos-derive` doing something wrong, or has Cargo changed something recently? Anyone have a proper solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have mysteriously disappeared again in nightly-2020-06-13. I don't know what the cause was, but I guess this is resolved.